# Copy subversion repo temporarily to local machine

Tags: svn

I'll be working away from my home network for a while and want to mirror my network SVN repo to the machine I'll be using while away. I gather it involves svnsync, but I'm not sure the best approach that makes syncing the machine back to the network when I get home easiest. The server running subversion at home will be off while I'm away.

1. How do I copy my home repo to the machine I'll be using while away?
2. Once I return, how do I sync my commits made while away back to my home repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svnsync` will not work for this, as it's meant to distribute a central repository to one or more read-only mirrors and there isn't a way to merge your local (in your proposed setup) changes back to the parent repository. While you can configure an svnsync mirror to allow commits, what *actually* happens is that server proxies the commit and t's passed to the source server.

Take a look at [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).  I'm pretty sure it will let you commit locally (as a local git repository) while you're offline, then push everything back to your Subversion repository when you get back home.